# PerspectiveCamera without perspective correction for 3D

Tags: 3d, javafx, perspectivecamera

Is there something like a PerspectiveCamera without perspective correction for working in 3D?

Using ParallelCamera is not applicable because it is always at position zero and results in 3D are not intuitive.

Java docs:

> [...]This camera is always located at center of the window and looks along the positive z-axis.

Setting `fieldOfView` to a small value (i.e. 0.1) using the `PerspectiveCamera.setFieldOfView(double value)` method, still produce perspectiving view. But I need **no perspective correction**.

I've tried to extend `PerspectiveCamera`, but it is impossible, because the appropriate fields declared as private.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Using a [ParallelCamera](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/ParallelCamera.html) would appear to be an obvious solution.  I don't fully understand why using a `ParallelCamera` does not work for you.

Comment: i need the feature with flag "fixedEyeAtCameraZero", from Java docs: We recommend setting fixedEyeAtCameraZero to true if you are going to transform (move) the camera. Transforming the camera when fixedEyeAtCameraZero is set to false may lead to results that are not intuitive.